How can i have an IIS-debuggable frontend and backend app share the same app pool?
Using Visual Studio i created a backend app.
What i want is that i have a frontend app serving at /
and a backend app that's serving under /api (for example).
both of them should share the same app pool and should be easily deployable to azure
and it should be possible to debug it using the IIS command in launchsettings.json
IIS-wise i'm able to configure it. i have a web.config in my sln root and have a handler registered at api/* for aspnetcore app, and one more at * for static files in that order.
now the problem is, the root path of the created app will be my .sln root, so when debugging my backend app, it will tell me there is another application at localhost/ and it wants to rewrite the path, which is wrong.
but when i now try to put my frontend into the csproj folder, then i would only reach it via /frontend, which is of course bad.
I even tried URL Rewrite even though i'd prefer to not have to resort to it, but when i did, it just gave me "something is wrong with your configuration" with empty spaces in the section where it should write the broken code, so i have no idea what was wrong.
what i definitely don't want is to serve my frontend via .UseStaticFiles(), because if i understand correctly, this'd require the .net application to be running when the frontend is.
i hope someone that knows about IIS can help me, thanks already.

While on IIS you are using URL rewrite module to hook the two together, in VS it’s more common to use frontend side proxy to achieve the same, and adapt to the VS convention of running ASP.NET Core apps as a site.

You can try to deploy the front-end project in the root path / and the back-end project in /api. Configure the request routing through the web.config file of IIS to ensure that the front-end processes static files and the back-end processes API requests. When debugging, point the back-end debugging path to /api through launchsettings.json. The front-end runs independently and does not rely on the back-end service. This achieves separation of the front-end and back-end, shares the same application pool, and is easy to deploy to Azure.

@meiquan that's what i want to avoid, because we want to deploy it to azure to one application to save costs. while, at the same time, ensuring that the startup of the backend app doesn't affect the starting time of the frontend (which would be the case with .UseStaticFiles() or so, if i recall correctly)

If I correctly understood,

FrontEnd application should not be served from the root files and be accessed as "/"
Backend application should serve at /api folder.

The solution is
With the IIS HTTP Redirect module, redirect "/" to "/frontend" but when enabling HTTP Redirect choose
"Only redirect requests to content in this directory (not subdirectories)" checkbox so that subfolders do not inherit this redirection. Therefore http requests to api folder will not be redirected.

the problem is i didn't even get the rewrite at all to be running. it gave ma a configuration error when i tried it with an IIS error page, but no details about what error, and just a blank line in the code quote, so i'm really lost, so i guess this is not working or me :/ i need to add that i'm definitely not an IIS expert

You may use simpler HTTP redirect module instead of "URL Rewrite" module. It can be installed directly from OS (Server Manager) as outlined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/
